# Valgrind leak detection with segfault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I'm checking my code for memory leaks. Everything is okay until I got the code:

```
mSystem = new LightSystem();
sf::View *view = th::DisplayManager::Get()->GetCamera();
mSystem->SetView(*view);
```

`SetView` does really tiny job (extracts a few members of passed `view` pointer. When latest code line is commented everything is okay, but uncommenting everything works in default mode and fails in memory leak detection with valgrind (`valgrind --tool=memcheck ./Binary`).

```
==23703== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==23703==    at 0x6B8472: ltbl::LightSystem::SetView(sf::View const&) (LightSystem.cpp:55)
==23703==    by 0x6A7A7D: th::LightManager::Initialize() (LightManager.cpp:46)
==23703==    by 0x6A75EA: th::Root::Initialize() (Root.cpp:101)
==23703==    by 0x6A7113: th::Root::Root() (Root.cpp:66)
==23703==    by 0x6A7553: th::Root::Get() (Root.cpp:88)
==23703==    by 0x6291A8: th::Game::Initialize() (Game.cpp:36)
==23703==    by 0x61DC1C: main (main.cpp:82)
==23703== 
==23703== Invalid read of size 8
==23703==    at 0x6B8472: ltbl::LightSystem::SetView(sf::View const&) (LightSystem.cpp:55)
==23703==    by 0x6A7A7D: th::LightManager::Initialize() (LightManager.cpp:46)
==23703==    by 0x6A75EA: th::Root::Initialize() (Root.cpp:101)
==23703==    by 0x6A7113: th::Root::Root() (Root.cpp:66)
==23703==    by 0x6A7553: th::Root::Get() (Root.cpp:88)
==23703==    by 0x6291A8: th::Game::Initialize() (Game.cpp:36)
==23703==    by 0x61DC1C: main (main.cpp:82)
==23703==  Address 0x8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==23703== 
==23703== 
==23703== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==23703==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x8
==23703==    at 0x6B8472: ltbl::LightSystem::SetView(sf::View const&) (LightSystem.cpp:55)
==23703==    by 0x6A7A7D: th::LightManager::Initialize() (LightManager.cpp:46)
==23703==    by 0x6A75EA: th::Root::Initialize() (Root.cpp:101)
==23703==    by 0x6A7113: th::Root::Root() (Root.cpp:66)
==23703==    by 0x6A7553: th::Root::Get() (Root.cpp:88)
==23703==    by 0x6291A8: th::Game::Initialize() (Game.cpp:36)
==23703==    by 0x61DC1C: main (main.cpp:82)
==23703==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==23703==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==23703==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==23703==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==23703==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
```

The questions are: why does it works successfully without valgrind and breaks with it.
I have also tried to set `--main-stacksize=` a big value but it didn't help me.

Comment: It probably doesn't "work" without valgrind.  It's getting undefined behavior because you're using an invalid pointer, meaning that anything can happen.

Comment: Don't forget that the problem doesn't have to be related to the `mSystem->SetView(*view);` line. You might have corrupted anywhere in the memory anytime before that point. Valgrind might just be changing where things are...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> ==23703== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
> ==23703==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x8
> ```

At some point (probably `LightSystem.cpp:55`) you're dereferencing a pointer to which you assigned `8` which looks nothing like a valid address.

Comment: So strange, I have checked all pointers (`view` before and after) and everything seems to be okay